# Timer for threads in c programming language

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

At the main of code, I want to create a thread (mythread) and stop main for 20Sec, while this time (20 Sec) mythread is processed and after 20 Sec main is resumed. What should i do?

Comment: Why do you need threads if you only have one thing to do at a time?

Comment: okay what aren't you telling us...

Comment: I want test threads,mythread should be run in 20Sec,and at this time main should wait,after this time main resume.

Comment: This makes no sense to me. It sounds like a single thread with an alarm would be entirely sufficient...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be nothing special you need to do. If you want the main thread to stop, just don't code it to do any work (or call a sleep function). If you want the thread to be processed, code it to do something. You should be focusing on what work you want your program to do though, not on the threads.

Comment: I am try it with sleep(),and i resolve it.Thank you.